# Is there a way send pulses over a DC line?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, avr, microchip, power-line-communication

more details :
we have 12V dc & we have master mcu board supply voltage to other slave mcu board the length of 12v dc cable between two boards can reach 50 meters so what is suggestion communicate master mcu board & slave mcu board ove 12v dc cable? master mcu board send request to slave mcu board to get a string like "hello world" over 12V dc

Comment: By "over a DC line" do you mean that you want to send data over a line that is carrying DC current to power a load at the other end? You need to edit your question to clarify this and state what frequency and, possibly, what the duty cycle of the data pulses will be.

Comment: if "DC" line **is** a power-carrying line, which powers, voltages, currents are we talking?

Comment: Many applications communicate long distances over power lines. How to do it depends what you need, so unless you can provide info what voltages, currents, and data rates you are talking about, the question can't be answered.

Comment: @Justme dc voltage 12V second mcu draw current 30ma

Comment: It sounds like you're after some manner of *power line communication*. This is not easy to arrange, as you will see from searching those keywords. You will have a much easier time just using a separate wire (or two).

Comment: @MarcusMüller dc voltage as 12V second mcu draw current 30ma so for data I have an idea for example to let first mcu send pulse as 10ms then other mcu measure the pulse how to implement it?

Comment: @Smarta, as mentioned in my first comment, you need to **edit your question** and add the missing information. Don't bury it in the comments (which can be deleted). Make it easy for those you are asking to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Without any other information in the question, which we'll just have to assume is appropriate (we'll soon know if this strawman turns out to be wrong), the safest option is an opto-isolated current loop.

This was the way 9600 baud serial communication was implemented around my electrically noisy sprawling industrial campus when we had one central PDP 11/70 serving a number of remote terminals.

One MCU drives a small current through the LED of an opto isolator located at the receiving MCU. This avoids problems from different ground potentials at the two sites. Cheap optos will happily work up to 10 kHz, you'll have to interrogate their specifications if you want to go much faster.